# Oracle SQL Developer: scheduled jobs

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

How to run jobs manually which are scheduled already in oracle sql developer?

I surfed through webpages but couldn't get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste the code from the job into a new worksheet and run it that way.

Comment: Yes That's working, Thank you. Is that a only way to run it manually...?

Comment: There may be a run button when you right click on the job? Don't have access to sql developer right now to confirm.

Comment: I cant see run option over there in any of the options. Thank you for your update. If you find something related with this manual running please update it over here.